# Html Webpack Plugin - How do you import headers/footer html partials into body template

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I'm trying to figure out a way where you can have an index file that when compiled loads the global header and footer into the index.html file so I don't have to add this every time.

At the moment this is what creates my index.html file:

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Typescript Webpack Starter',
        template: '!!ejs-loader!src/index.html'
    }),
```

It loads the JS in the body and the css in the head fine but I'm wondering if I can do something like the below (just like a template engine would)

```
  <body>
       {{HEADER GETS IMPORTED HERE}}
       <p>Success your page has loaded</p>
       <button class="button">Button</button>
       {{FOOTER GETS IMPORTED HERE}}
  </body>
```

Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official [document](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) : **YOU CAN ACHIEVE** it.

If you already have a template loader, you can use it to parse the template. Please note that this will also happen if you specifiy the html-loader and use .html file as template.

```
 module: {
   loaders: [
     { test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "handlebars" }
   ]
 },
 plugins: [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     title: 'Custom template using Handlebars',
     template: 'my-index.hbs'
   })
 ]
```

Comment: So you suggest using an actual template engine to do it? I thought there might of been a way to do this with using webpack somehow :O

Comment: So, it's not out of the way.
Webpack just understand JavaScript. So we have different loaders for them and then numerous plugins to achieve the desired output.

In your case, just need to install 'handlebars' loader and then configure 'HtmlWebpackPlugin' for that :)

Comment: Hi Ravi, I've followed your answer and I'm having an unexpected error that I've logged here. If you have a moment would you be able to suggest anything please? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826337/webpack-2-handlbar-loader-module-parse-failed-error

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody needs a working example. I did it with an [ejs-loader](https://github.com/tracker1/ejs-render-loader)

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
   <%- include partials/header.ejs %>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <%- include partials/footer.ejs %>
</div>
```

Also put evth. into a small [webpack boilerplate](https://github.com/web-designed/scrapp) there are some more extras inside ;) feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Since html-loader replaced option interpolate with preprocessor, the solution for webpack5 and html-loader 3.0.1 is:

```
preprocessor: (content, loaderContext) =>
      content.replace(
        /<include src="(.+)"\s*\/?>(?:<\/include>)?/gi,
        (m, src) => {
          const filePath = path.resolve(loaderContext.context, src)
          loaderContext.dependency(filePath)
          return fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')
        }
      ),
```

Solution I've got from here [github](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/291) after a half of hours of surfing.
Probably it helps to someone.